Volume Scattering Rays Clipping when camera is close to them
When my camera gets inside the volume it clips and disappears, i am guessing it has to do something with the clipping but i can't seem to find a setting that will fix it, i changed the camera near clipping to 0 and the problem was still occurring. I will leave a link for you to see the problem.
https://youtu.be/Ip5G6X9v2io?si=SscMnIVvbR4LUEwp
